# My 100% width is only 100% in browser, not on the mobile

Tags: html, css

I have both my navigation bars set to 100% as well as my background colors and images but the nav bars are like 105%, they stretch further than the phone size and give a horizontal scroll. What could the problem be?

Comment: do you have a container larger than the window, with `overflow:hidden`? because that is a well-known bug, that overflow items are not hidden on mobile like on browser, and the 100% is based on the container size.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about iOs i  had a font-size issue a while ago wich i solved with

```
body {
    -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
}
```

also make sure to normalize or reset your css before applying your style to avoid default browser style issues

Comment: I needed my nav bars to be set at max-width:100% no width:100%,

Comment: -webkit-text-size-adjus affects text size which may be pushing you width over the 100% you set.
It was a wild guess since i don't have code to look at